# Index of Last Active Transaction

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a stream of transaction of three types, the `+` transaction increase an index (starting with 1).

The `=` transaction
keeps the index without a change. Starting with `NULL`.

The `-` transaction negates the effect of the last `+` transaction and returns to the previous value or to NULL.

The transactions on different `ID`'s are independent, within `ID` ordered on `SEQ`

There are some consistency rules: `-` must follow (direct or indirect) a `+` and `-` can not follow an `-` (i.e. no nested negations). `=` cann occure in any number in between.

So with the sample data (see below) this is the expected result (column `LAST_IDX`)

```
        ID        SEQ CODE   LAST_IDX
---------- ---------- ---- ----------
         1          1 +             1 
         1          2 =             1 
         1          3 =             1 
         1          4 +             2 
         1          5 =             2 
         1          6 -             1 
         1          7 =             1 
         1          8 +             3 
         1          9 =             3 
         1         10 -             1 
         2          1 +             1
```

I started with this analytic function

```
SUM(decode(code,'+',1,'-',-1,0)) over (partition by id order by seq)
```

which is nearly done, except that the `+` in `seq = 8` goes to 2 and not to 3.

So finaly I managed this solution which works

```
select ID, SEQ, CODE,
  case when   LAST_VALUE(decode(code,'+','+','-','-') ignore nulls) 
              over (partition by id order by seq ) = '+' then
       SUM(decode(code,'+',1,0)) over (partition by id order by seq) 
  else    
       SUM(decode(code,'+',1,'-',-1,0)) over (partition by id order by seq)       
  end  as last_idx
from tab order by id, seq;
```

But I expect there must be a much simple solution.

Any ideas?

Sample Data

```
create table tab as
select 1 id, 1 seq, '+' code from dual union all
select 1 id,2 seq, '=' code from dual union all
select 1 id,3 seq, '=' code from dual union all
select 1 id,4 seq, '+' code from dual union all
select 1 id,5 seq, '=' code from dual union all
select 1 id,6 seq, '-' code from dual union all
select 1 id,7 seq, '=' code from dual union all
select 1 id,8 seq, '+' code from dual union all
select 1 id,9 seq, '=' code from dual union all
select 1 id,10 seq, '-' code from dual  union all
select 2 id, 1 seq, '+' code from dual;
```

Comment: Your explanation of the logic of the codes and of the results doesn't match.  The `+` doesn't increment by 1, it increments based on the maximum previous value.  Then the "-" afterwards doesn't go to 2 it goes to 1.  I don't understand.

Comment: @Gordon Let’s reformulate a bit. Each plus increase the index by one (independent of minuses). The minus negates (cancels) the previous plus and returns the index to the last plus that was not negated. So formulated, it seems that there are indeed two different calculations dependent on the plus / minus in the last transaction. After this discussion I’m not so sure there would be a more simple solution, but I’ll wait some time before close…

Comment: @MarmiteBomber, for the row with ID = 1 and SEQ = 3, if its CODE would be '-', what will be the LAST_IDX value?

Comment: @AndreiOdegov index will go to `NULL`, the same index is used if the first tranasction is `=`. Sorry for not covering it in my example.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really quite an answer, because it re-affirms the OP's solution.

Your description of the operators over-simplifies what they do.  I think the solution you came up with is the best solution.  I would write it as:

```
select id, seq, code,
       (case when last_value(case code when '+' then '+' when '-' then '-' end ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by seq ) = '+'
             then sum(case code when '+' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by seq) 
             else sum(case code when '+' then 1 when '-' then -1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by seq)       
        end) as last_idx
from tab
order by id, seq;
```

Essentially, you have two different methods depending on whether the current code is `'+'` or `'-'`, and that is what your logic expresses.

Your solution is very interesting.  My first reaction to the operations is that a recursive CTE (or hierarchical query) would be needed.  However, you can cleanly separate the logic for the two operations, so there is a more efficient solution.